# how do i get the total array length in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

i'm trying to get the total result length but i'm not getting anything in my template
this my script

```
  data() {
    return {
      searchResults: [],
      totalResults: [],
}}
       const response = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/search",
          searchData
        );
        this.searchResults = response.data.Response.Results; // Set the search results in the component's data       // Retrieve the traceId from the response
        const nestedResults = response.data.Response.Results;
        const totalResults = nestedResults[0].length;
        console.log("Total Results:", totalResults);
```

this is my console i'm getting totalResults

```
Total Results: 12
```

this my template

```
 <p>Total Results: {{ totalResults }}</p>
```

template returns this

```
Total Results: []
```

i dont get anything in my template please how can i go about this

Comment: What do you get on your template?

Comment: @L_Cleo Total Results: []

Comment: You declare ```totalResults``` two times. **data(){return{ totalResults:[] }}** and **const totalResults=**. If you want to pass the total result, just *remove* ```const``` and change to ```this.totalResults = nestedResults[0].length;``` Then set totalResults from *totalResults:[]* to *totalResults:null*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off you're initializing a variable that should be a number, with an empty array. You should have:

```
data() {
    return {
      searchResults: [],
      totalResults: 0,
}}
```

Second of all you're not assigning the value to the correct totalResults, you're simply declaring a new variable. To assign the value you should use `this.totalResults`. Therefore

```
this.totalResults = nestedResults[0].length;
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help, if it solved your issue could you kindly mark it as a correct answer?